# Отключить автоматическое прокладывание маршрута, на сайте с карты гугл ( bitrix)

Tags: битрикс, google-maps-api, google-maps

Как отключить автоматическое прокладывание маршрута на картах  установленных на сайте.
Проблема: выскакивает окно о доступе к геоданным.

Comment: как подключаете карту? никогда не наблюдал такого в штатном компоненте.

Comment: bitrix/map.google.system/ вот эта штука, прости за поздний ответ думал уже не напишет никто. Она изначально в шаблоне была эта катра, так что хз @nikolaj

Comment: попробуйте использовать компонент map.google.view